# Method of characteristics for a PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

Find the solution to the PDE using the method of characteristics

$$x^2u_{x}+xyu_{y}=u^{2}$$

such that it passes through the curve $u=1$ when $x=y^{2}$.

I can obtain the characteristic equations as follows:

$$\frac{dx}{ds}=x^{2}$$
$$\frac{dy}{ds}=xy$$
$$\frac{du}{ds}=u^{2}$$

Solving these yields the following characteristics:

$$x(s)=-\frac{1}{s+c_{x}}$$
$$y(s)=\frac{c_{y}}{s+c_{x}}$$
$$u(s)=-\frac{1}{s+c_{u}}$$

At this point it is unclear to me how we proceed utilizing the fact that $u=1$ when $x=y^{2}$. I feel like I am missing something pretty important, but I cannot seem to find what that is. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a point on the curve $x=y^2$, say $(x,y)=(a^2,a)$. It is given that $u=1$ at such a point. We can assume that the characteristic curve through the point $(x,y,u)=(a^2,a,1)$ passes it when $s=0$. So you can let $x(0)=a^2$, $y(0)=a$ and $u(0)=1$ to solve for $c_x$, $c_y$ and $c_u$. Once this is done, you know $x$, $y$ and $u$ as functions of $a$ and $s$. Now take the expressions for $x$ and $y$ and try to solve for $a$ and $s$, and then insert the resulting expressions for $a=a(x,y)$ and $s=s(x,y)$ into the expression for $u$, to obtain the solution $u(x,y)$.

Comment: when I go to write $u$ in terms of $a=a(x,y)$ and $s=s(x,y)$ it turns out that since $u$ is not explicitly written in terms of $a$ that my solution becomes $u(x,y) = \frac{x^{2}}{x^{2}+x-y^{2}}$ which when inserted into the original PDE satisfies it. I appreciate your thoughtful response!